# Time delay of sound files using cross correlation

Tags: java, signal-processing, audio-processing, cross-correlation

I'm trying to speed up my algorithm of time delay estimation between two sound files in Java. My idea was to use cross correlation and search for the highest value which gives me the amount of samples that are delayed.

I've done this and its working just fine. I created some sample files and then calculated the time delay. The result is pretty good. The problem is, that the algorithm takes a lot of time because of the large amount of operations.

Is there any way to speed this up?

```
/**
 * Input vector for signal x1 (reference).
 */
private double[] x1;

/**
 * Input vector for signal x2 (test).
 */
private double[] x2;


/**
 * Execute the cross correlation between signal x1 and x2 and calculate the time delay.
 */
public void execCorrelation()
{
    // define the size of the resulting correlation field
    int corrSize = 2*x1.length;
    // create correlation vector
    out = new double[corrSize];
    // shift variable
    int shift = x1.length;
    double val;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    double maxVal = 0;

    // we have push the signal from the left to the right
    for(int i=0;i<corrSize;i++)
    {
        val = 0;
        // multiply sample by sample and sum up
        for(int k=0;k<x1.length;k++)
        {
            // x2 has reached his end - abort
            if((k+shift) > (x2.length -1))
            {
                break;
            }

            // x2 has not started yet - continue
            if((k+shift) < 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // multiply sample with sample and sum up
            val += x1[k] * x2[k+shift];
            //System.out.print("x1["+k+"] * x2["+(k+tmp_tau)+"] + ");
        }
        //System.out.println();
        // save the sample
        out[i] = val;
        shift--;
        // save highest correlation index
        if(out[i] > maxVal)
        {
            maxVal = out[i];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

    // set the delay
    this.delay = maxIndex - x1.length;
}
```

Comment: You have a *for-if* pattern where you check for the boundaries of the sample. You could speed this up a tiny bit by instead calculating the start and end of the inner loop once.

Comment: Also, your result is weighted, as small shifts will have more valid combinations, so the sum of the correlation rises in absolute value.

Comment: What do you mean with "weighted" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, a cross-correlation is the same as convolution with one of the signals time-reversed. A convolution in turn is efficiently calculated by multiplying the spectra of the two signals; i.e., take the FFT of each signal padded at least to the sum of the size of both signals, multiply the FFT transformed spectra, do an inverse IFFT, and search for your peak.

For Java, you can use [JTransforms](https://github.com/wendykierp/JTransforms) to do the FFT/IFFT.

If you want to play with this approach before actually implementing it, you can try my application [FScape](https://bintray.com/sciss/generic/FScape); it has a convolution module that takes two sound files (you tagged the question "audio-processing", so I assume you can generate sound files).

Comment: That assumes the signal is cyclic.

Comment: @SimonRichter - what do you mean? You do the padding to prevent time aliasing; see [cross-correlation properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Properties) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Yes, if the signal is padded, this works (plus the phase angle of the peak gives you a finer resolution).

Comment: @SimonRichter - thx for your reply. I already implemented FFT but I'm not sure how to use it for the correlation. I use FFT of apache math and the output of the FFT is complex. So i multiplied the complex vectors of FFT{x1} and FFT{x2*}. So i have a Complex[] array. The IFFT input requires double[] values. So now I'm not sure what to use for IFFT. Real, or absolute value of the complex array ? Sorry, im new to this FFT/IFFT things.

Comment: Do a complex multiplication of the FFT results, then use the complex -> complex iFFT function, and search for the largest absolute value (`re*re+im*im`, no need to calculate the square root).

Comment: thanks that is working and it's also really fast. I still have some questions. I followed this guide for fast convolution:

http://www.music.miami.edu/programs/mue/Research/jvandekieft/jvchapter2.htm

They say i have to zero pad the signals before FFT to: N_x + N_y -1. Why i have to do?

Another point: If the zero padded signal give me a block size which is not a power of two, i can not calc the FFT. So i will have to round up/down to match this fact. Is this also a problem?

Comment: You can round up the FFT size to a power of two if the algorithm requires that. As for why the padding: Imagine your second signal is a dirac impulse in the last sample frame - that produces a delay of N_y - 1. If you don't allow for N_y - 1 samples padding, the delayed N_x will be "wrapped around" the FFT window, i.e. time is aliased.